# Android Create indicator service

Tags: android, firebase, android-service

I want to create app with service that other apps that listen to this service-app, will get indicator that the firebase DB has change.

My service need just to add notification that the DB has change,
and the other app that listen to this service will show a toast message.

This is my Service code  that I try (I'm almost sure it's wrong), but I don't know  which event I need to override for popup notification to all the receivers

```
 public TravelStatusService() {


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        final DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TraveRequest");
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            //HERE I WANT TO RETURN CHANGE NOTIFICATION
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//                Toast.makeText(this,"database error",
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return  null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Why you can not do this in the app itself?

Comment: I need to try create service and try to listen from my app, that the reason for create an app service, thanks